# Raspberry pi 3 B+ не запускается

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

При запуске выдаёт такую строку:
[image: Raspberry pi 3 B+ не запускается.]

При нажатии Control D ничего не происходит. Перестала запускаться после обычного завершения работы.

Comment: у тебя скорее всего что-то с флехой, корень смонтировался в ридонли. запусти проверку фс. вот оно и не грузиться в нормальном режиме.

Answer (score 1):

Там достаточно ясно написано. Прямо в первой строке:

> Ошибка при попытке запуска проверки файловой системы на корневом
> устройстве

Битая у Вас файловая система на флэшке. Перепишите.

После ошибки загрузчик отмонтировал рутовую файловую систему и рекомендует Вам посмотреть сислог:

```
journalctl -xb
```

Там и ищите причину ошибки.